# stokesCavity example for FiPy returns False

Tags: python, fipy

I have tried to run the  [stokesCavity](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/blob/86aaa5c2ba2c6f1be19593c5986071cf6568cc34/examples/flow/stokesCavity.py) example, which uses lid-driven boundary conditions for the flow. At the end of the code, the values in the top-right cell are compared with some reference values.

```py
>>> print(numerix.allclose(pressure.globalValue[..., -1], 162.790867927)) #doctest: +NOT_PYAMGX_SOLVER
1
>>> print(numerix.allclose(xVelocity.globalValue[..., -1], 0.265072740929)) #doctest: +NOT_PYAMGX_SOLVER
1
>>> print(numerix.allclose(yVelocity.globalValue[..., -1], -0.150290488304)) #doctest: +NOT_PYAMGX_SOLVER
1
```

When I tried running this example, my output was
**False**
**False**
**False**
The actual values I get for the top-right cell are **129.235**, **0.278627** and **-0.166620** (instead of 162.790867927, 0.265072740929 and -0.150290488304). Does anyone know why am I getting different values? I've tried changing the solver (used scipy, Trilinos and pysparse), but the results do not change up to the 12th digit. The velocity profile looks similar to the one shown in their [manual](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/flow/generated/examples.flow.stokesCavity.html), but I am still worried something is off.
I run it on Linux (python 2.7.14, fipy 3.2, pysparse 1.2.dev0, Trilinos 12.12, scipy 1.2.1) and  on Windows (python 2.7.15, fipy 3.1.3, scipy 1.1.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run as part of the test suite, this example only does 5 sweeps, and the numerical check is hard-wired for this. When you run the example in isolation, it does 300 sweeps and the solution is better (or at least differently) converged. There's nothing wrong with the example, other than it's [not written in a very robust way](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/671). Thanks for asking about this; we'll try to clean up the example.